# Conversion from Date to POSIXct object - error by one hour

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert a date object (obtained from user input via Shiny) to a POSIXct object - I want to get to the bottom of why an hour is added to the obtained POSIXct object in spite of both objects having the same timezone.

See code below. I tried finding and answer on google or the Stackoverflow forum, without success.

```
> "2019-05-11" %>% as.Date(tz = "UTC") %>% as.POSIXct(tz = "UTC")
[1] "2019-05-11 01:00:00 BST"

> "2019-05-11" %>% as.Date(tz = "GMT") %>% as.POSIXct(tz = "GMT")
[1] "2019-05-11 01:00:00 BST"
```

I have entered the lines above at the console (RStudio). I would have expected the POSIXct objects to be

```
"2019-05-11 00:00:00 BST".
```

Does anyone get this? I want to avoid manipulating the results above by subtracting from the POSIXct object in case the issue above has to do with my computer (clock) and might not exist on a computer where I intend to deploy my Shiny app.

I'm not very much of an expert about R or computers in general, and I would be grateful for an answer without too much jargon.

Comment: the output is in your local time zone, which seems to be "BST", so GMT+1

Comment: you can type `Sys.setenv(TZ="UTC")` before your code to get your expected result

Comment: Thanks, that sorted it! Thanks for your prompt help!

Comment: ok, I post it as an answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output is in your local time zone, which seems to be "BST" = GMT+1, which is why you see that added hour

You can add this line before your code to make your timezone UTC

```
Sys.setenv(TZ="UTC")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change your `locales` right now. `?timezones` yields:

> A time zone region may be known by several names: for example
>   "Europe/London" is also known as GB, GB-Eire, Europe/Belfast,
>   Europe/Guernsey, Europe/Isle_of_Man and Europe/Jersey.

So we may use `strftime` after `as.POSIXct` and set `tz="GB"` for both calls. Magically `"BST"` appears as time zone abbreviation after the expected time.

```
tm <- "2019-05-11"
strftime(as.POSIXct(tm, tz="GB"), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z", tz="GB")
# [1] "2019-05-11 00:00:00 BST"
```

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I realise strftime would return a character. What I was looking for was a POSIXct object that I could calculate with.